# ParserError: Expected type name

Tags: solidity

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

 contract helloworld{

     string Name ="mmo";


  function  getName(?) public pure  returns(string)
  {
 return Name;
 }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to precise the data location of your returned string.

See here:

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

 contract helloworld{

    string Name ="mmo";

    function  getName() public view returns(string memory)
    {
        return Name;
    }
}
```

also, you need to declare your function as 'view', not 'pure', since you are reading from a state variable.

And one last thing, by convention, state variable don't really start with capital letters so maybe 'name' is better than 'Name' for your string.

Hope this helps!